# Why we need framework to do the Dependency Resolver?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, dependencies

I always saw people always talking about using framework like Ninject, Unity, Windsor to do the dependency resolver and injection. Take following code for example:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    private IProductRepository _repository;

    public ProductsController(IProductRepository repository)  
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

My question is: why can't we simply write as:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    private IProductRepository _repository;

    public ProductsController() :this(null)
    {}

    public ProductsController(IProductRepository repository)  
    {
        _repository = repository?? new ProductRepository();
    }
}
```

In that case seems we don't need any framework, even for the unit test we can easily mock.

So what's the real purpose for those framework?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case your `ProductsController` still depends on a low level component (the concrete `ProductRepository` in your case) which is a violation of the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). Whether or not this is a problem depends on multiple factors, but it causes the following problems:

- The creation of the `ProductRepository` is still duplicated throughout the application causing you to make sweeping changes throughout the application when the constructor of `ProductRepository` chances (assuming that `ProductRepository` is used in more places, which is quite reasonable) which would be an [Open/Closed Principle violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).
- It causes you to make sweeping changes whenever you decide to wrap this `ProductService` with a decorator or interceptor that adds cross-cutting concerns (such as logging, audit trailing, security filtering, etc) that you surely don't want to repeat that code throughout all your repositories (again an OCP violation).
- It forces the `ProductsController` to know about the `ProductsRepository`, which *might* be a problem depending on the size and complexity of the application your are writing.

So this is not about the use of frameworks, it's about applying software design principles. If you decide to adhere to these principles to make your application more maintainable, the frameworks like Ninject, Autofac and Simple Injector can help you with making the startup path of your application more maintainable. But nothing is preventing you from applying these principles without the use of any tool or library.

Answer (score 3):

Small disclaimer: I'm an *avid* Unity user, and here are my 2 cents.

### 1st: Violation of SOLID (SRP/OCP/DIP)

Already stated by @democodemonkey and @thumbmunkeys, you couple the 2 classes tightly. Let's say that some classes (let it be ProductsThingamajigOne and ProductsThingamajigTwo) are using the ProductsController, and are using its default constructor. What if in the architect decides that the system should not use a ProductsRepository that saves Products into files, but should use a database or a cloud storage. What would the impact be on the classes?

### 2nd: What if the ProductRepository needs another dependency?

If the repository is based on a database, you might need to provide it with a ConnectionString. If it's based on files, you might need to provide it with a class of settings providing the exact path of where to save the files - and the truth is, that in general, applications tend to contain dependency trees (A dependent on B and C, B dependent on D, C dependent on E, D dependent on F and G and so on) that have more then 2 levels, so the SOLID violations hurts more, as more code has to be changed to perform some task - but even before that, can you imagine the code that would create the whole app? 
Fact is, classes can have many dependencies of theirs own - and in this case, the issues described earlier multiply.

That's usually the job of the Bootstrapper - it defines the dependency structure, and performs (usually) a single resolve that brings the whole system up, like a puppet on a string.

### 3rd: What if the Dependency-Tree is not a tree, but a Graph?

Consider the following case: Class A dependent on classes B and C, B and C both are dependent on class D, and are expecting to use the same instance of D. A common practice was to make D a singleton, but that could cause a lot of issues. The other option is to pass an instance of D into the constructor of A, and have it create B and C, or pass instances of B and C to A and create them outside - and the complexity goes on and on.

### 4th: Packing (Assemblies)

Your code assumes that 'ProductsController' can see 'ProductRepository' (assembly-wise). What if there's no reference between them? the Assembly Map can be non-trivial. usually, the bootstrapping code (I'm assuming that it's in code and not in configuration file for a second here) is written in an assembly that references the entire solution. (This was also described by @Steven).

### 5th: Cool stuff you can do with IoC containers

Singletons are made easy (with unity: simply use a 'containercontrolledlifetimemanager' when registering), 
Lazy Instantiation made really easy (with unity: register mapping of  and ask in the constructor for a Func).
Those are just a couple of examples of things that IoC containers give you for (almost) free.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you could do that, but this would cause the following issues:

- The dependency to `IProductRepository` is not explicit anymore, it looks like an optional dependency
- Other parts of the code might instantiate a different implementation of `IProductRepository`, which would be probably a problem in this case
- The class becomes tightly coupled to `ProductsController` as it internally creates a dependency

In my opinion this is not a question about a framework. The point is to make modules composable, by exposing their dependencies in a constructor or property. Your example somewhat obfuscates that.

Answer (score 1):

If class `ProductRepository` is not defined in the same assembly as `ProductsController` (or if you would ever want to move it to a different assembly) then you have just introduced a dependency that you don't want.

That's an anti-pattern described as "Bastard Injection" in the seminal book "Dependency Injection in .Net" by Mark Seeman.

However, if `ProductRepository` is ALWAYS going to be in the same assembly as `ProductsController` and if it does not depend on anything that the rest of the `ProductsController` assembly depends upon, it could be a `local default` - in which case it would be ok.

From the class names, I'm betting that such a dependency SHOULD NOT be introduced, and you are looking at bastard injection.

Answer (score 0):

Here `ProductsController` is responsible for creating the `ProductRepository`.

What happens if `ProductRepository` requires an additional parameter in its constructor? Then `ProductsController` will have to change, and this violates the SRP.

As well as adding more complexity to all of your objects.

As well as making it unclear as to whether a caller needs to pass the child object, or is it optional?

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose is to decouple object creation from its usage or consumption. The creation of the object "usually" is taken care of by factory classes. In your case, the factory classes will be designed to return an object of a type which implements `IProductRepository` interface.

In some frameworks, like in Sprint.Net, the factory classes instantiate objects that are declaratively written in the configuration (i.e. in the app.config or web.config). Thus making the program totally independent of the object it needs to create. This can be quite powerful at times.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to distinguish dependency injection and inversion of control is not the same. You can using dependency injection without IOC frameworks like unity, ninject ..., performing the injection manually what they often called poor man's DI.

In my blog I recently wrote a post about this issue 
http://xurxodeveloper.blogspot.com.es/2014/09/Inyeccion-de-Dependencias-DI.html

Going back to your example, I see weaknesses in the implementation.

1 - ProductsController depends on a concretion and not an abstraction, violation SOLID

2 - In case of interface and the repository are living in different projects, you'd be forced to have a reference to the project where the repository is located

3 -If in the future you need to add a parameter to the constructor, you would have to modify the controller when it's a simply repository client.

4 -Controller and repository can be developed for differents programmers, controller programmer must know how create repository

Answer (score 0):

consider this usecase:

suppose, in future, if you want to inject `CustomProductRepository` instead of `ProductRepository` to `ProductsController` , to the software which is already deployed to client site.

with Spring.Net you can just update the spring configuration file(xml) to use your `CustomProductRepository`. So, with this, you can avoid re-compiling and re-installing software on client site since you have not modified any code.